# In Spades, who wins if both partnerships reach more than 500?

Tags: spades

If the final score is 504 to 505? Who wins? You both reached 500 exactly and the 5 and the 4 are just indicators of bags. So who wins? The person with less bags or do you just play one more round?

Answer (score 4):

The partnership that have more points.  That is the partnership that scored 505.  The 1 points per overtrick is a real point, not just an indicator of bags.

From [Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/auctionwhist/spades.html):

> The side which reaches 500 points first wins the game. If both sides reach 500 points in the same deal, the side with the higher score wins.

Comment: Yes.  Bags are both liabilities and assets.